# How do I initialize this variable-size struct?

Tags: c++

How do I initialize the variable-size C++ struct "StructB" that is declared below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct {
 char* a;
 int b;
} StructA;

typedef struct {
  StructA* pointers[];
  int pcount;
  int numbers[];
  int ncount;
} StructB;

int main()
{
    StructB *sb = new StructB; // I need 'sb' to be allocated in the heap
    sb->pcount = 5;
    sb->ncount = 3;
    sb->pointers = new StructA*[sb->pcount];
    sb->numbers = int[sb->ncount];
}
```

I got these compiler errors. What do these error means and how do I fix them? THank you.

```
In function 'int main()': 
21:43: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'StructA**' to 'StructA* [0]' 
22:19: error: expected primary-expression before 'int' 
22:19: error: expected ';' before 'int'
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C++ and Standard C++ does not support VLA's.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `int numbers[];` is not allowed as a `struct` member in C++. It is allowed in C, but only as the last member - in other words, that `int ncount;` immediately afterwards also makes it illegal C.

Comment: Just make them `StructA **pointers;` and `int *numbers;`. Or, better yet, use vectors since this is C++ and not C.

Comment: @cdhowie: No, arrays are **not** pointers. (Arrays decay into pointers, though.)

Comment: @EduardoLeón I'm not sure that's true in all cases -- for example I am pretty sure that `void foo(int x[])` is equivalent to `void foo(int *x)`. ([The compiler agrees](http://ideone.com/jpRnV3).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listen this is not the good c++ way, you are doing C in a C++ environment
which is OK if it gives you some advantage (IO, typechecking, etc.) or for learning.
Dynamic allocation of memory in C style is entirely manual. So is deallocation.
Since you are using typedef, typedef can make things clearer for you and for the compiler.
Here is a tortured example which I think does what you want. 
Notice that it is done "The Hard Way" which is actually the easy way in this case of 
C style coding in C++;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


typedef struct {
char* a;
int b;
} StructA;


typedef StructA* A_p;   // A_p is "pointer to structA" (contains address of struct)                                                                           

typedef A_p* A_p_Array; // A_p_Array is "pointer to A_p"  (aka StructA**) contains address of A_p                                                             

typedef int* int_Array; // int_Array is "pointer to int" contains address of integer                                                                          


typedef struct {
 A_p_Array A_pointers;
 int pcount;
 int_Array numbers;
 int ncount;
} StructB;


int main()
{
 int i;

 StructA *sa = new StructA;

 StructB *sb = new StructB;

 sb->pcount = 5;
 sb->ncount = 3;

 A_p_Array  tmp_A_array;
 A_p        tmp;

 for ( i = 0 ; i < sb->pcount; i++)
 {
  tmp_A_array = new A_p; // create a StructA pointer                                                                                                      
  tmp = new StructA;     // create a StructA                                                                                                              
  tmp_A_array = &tmp;    // put address of tmp in mp_A_array                                                                                              
  tmp_A_array++;         // increment array address                                                                                                       
 }


 sb->A_pointers = tmp_A_array; // A_pointers now contains address of dynamically created array                                                               

 tmp_A_array = NULL;  // clear pointer but do NOT delete!                                                                                                    

 int_Array tmp_i_array;
 for ( i = 0 ; i < sb->ncount; i++)
 {
  tmp_i_array = new int(0); // c++ can create ints with initial values                                                                                    
  tmp_i_array++;
 }

 sb->numbers = tmp_i_array;
 tmp_i_array = NULL;  // clear pointer but do NOT delete!                                                                                                    


 /****** USE  Structs A & B    *****/

 // clean up the heap                                                                                                                                        

 A_p Ap;

 for ( i = 0 ; i < sb->pcount; i++)
 {
  Ap =  sb->A_pointers[i];
  delete Ap;  // each struct released separately
 }

 int* ip;
 for ( i = 0 ; i < sb->ncount; i++)
 {
  ip = & sb->numbers[i];
  delete ip;  //each int released separately
 }

 delete sb;

  return 0;
} // main
```

There are better ways to do the above
which is one reason c++ and higher languages were invented.
When you get to classes it will be somewhat easier
but you can run in to the same types of problems there
so getting pointers and pointers-to-pointers down
now will serve you in good stead later.